# How to redirect 404 page inside an axios service - nextjs

Tags: javascript, axios, next.js

I'm using axios.
I want to check status when I got response of my api.
for example I want to redirect to 404 page.

```
const api = axios.create({
  headers: {
    common: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    post: {

    }
  }
});
api.interceptors.response.use(
  ...

  (error) => {
const code = parseInt(error.response && error.response.status)
     if (code === 404) {
          console.log("responsive",error)
          if(data){
            data.forEach(itemError => {
              toast.error(itemError, {
                theme: 'colored',
              });
            });
          }else{
            //redirect to 404 page. but it doesn't work. 
            //return window.location.href = '/404';
          }
...
```

But I don't know How I can to redirect inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the useRouter hook https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router

Init the router in your functional component.

```
const router = useRouter();
```

Then redirects to any page

```
router.push('your-page')
```